# Stop main() function from starting automatically

Tags: python, function, file, if-statement, while-loop

**After the first run of the program**(when i input the choice) **the main function starts automatically again , i want to make it so that it doesnot start automatically ,instead ask if u want to run the program again or exit the program , if i chose to run the program the main() function starts again else the program ends.**

```
file=open("nomobile.txt","w")
text=" If The worLd was Ending , yOU WIll come over right, u will come over and stay the 9it"
file.write(text)

file=open("nomobile.txt",'r')
characters=file.read()


vowels=0

consonants=0

uppercase=0

lowercase=0

for ch in characters:

    if ch.islower():
        lowercase+=1
    elif ch.isupper():
        uppercase+=1
    ch=ch.lower()
    if ch in "aeiou":
        vowels+=1
    elif ch in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
        consonants+=1
file.close()

def main():
    
    while True:
        print("What do you want to know about?")
        print("Press 1 to know about uppercase letters")
        print("Press 2 to know about lowercase letters")
        print("Press 3 to know about vowels")
        print("Press 4 to know about consonants")
        print("Press 5 to know about all of them at once")

        choice=int(input("Press number:"))
        if choice == 1:
            print("The number of uppercase letters present are", uppercase)
        elif choice == 2:
            print("The number of lowercase letters present are", lowercase)
        elif choice == 3:
            print("The number of vowels present are",vowels)
        elif choice == 4:
            print("The number of consonants present are",consonants)
        elif choice == 5:
            print("The number of uppercase letters present are", uppercase)
            print("The number of lowercase letters present are", lowercase)
            print("The number of vowels present are",vowels)
            print("The number of consonants present are",consonants)
        else:
            break
        

main()
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: The question is this 
Read a text file and display the number of vowel consonant uppercase/lowercase
characters in a file. but i need to make it menu driven , but when i run the code first time, the main () function starts again after giving output

Comment: Your program should exit if enter any number other than 1 to 5.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add another prompt in the main function, i.e.:

```
from sys import exit

file = open("nomobile.txt", "w")
text = "If The worLd was Ending , yOU WIll come over right, u will come over and stay the 9it"
file.write(text)

file = open("nomobile.txt", "r")

characters = file.read()
vowels = 0
consonants = 0
uppercase = 0
lowercase = 0

for ch in characters:
    if ch.islower():
        lowercase += 1
    elif ch.isupper():
        uppercase += 1
    ch = ch.lower()
    if ch in "aeiou":
        vowels += 1
    elif ch in "bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz":
        consonants += 1
file.close()


def main():

    while True:
        print("What do you want to know about?")
        print("Press 1 to know about uppercase letters")
        print("Press 2 to know about lowercase letters")
        print("Press 3 to know about vowels")
        print("Press 4 to know about consonants")
        print("Press 5 to know about all of them at once")

        choice = int(input("Press number:"))
        if choice == 1:
            print("The number of uppercase letters present are", uppercase)
        elif choice == 2:
            print("The number of lowercase letters present are", lowercase)
        elif choice == 3:
            print("The number of vowels present are", vowels)
        elif choice == 4:
            print("The number of consonants present are", consonants)
        elif choice == 5:
            print("The number of uppercase letters present are", uppercase)
            print("The number of lowercase letters present are", lowercase)
            print("The number of vowels present are", vowels)
            print("The number of consonants present are", consonants)
        else:
            break

        print("Do you want to run the program again?")
        print("Press 0 to exit")
        print("Press 1 to continue")

        choice = int(input("Press number:"))
        if choice == 0:
            print("Exiting")
            exit(0)


main()
```

Comment: It would likely be much better to wrap `main()` in the `while` loop than add another scope within it!

Comment: Thankyou very much christopher , it worked